# Will GDPR override local privacy laws?

Tags: gdpr

[Here](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/privacy-law-by-country/) it seems all european(EEA) countries and iceland have their own privacy laws . Do we have to follow all of the laws as many do not seem to allow *legitimate interest*. I mean, is following GDPR enough for Europe?

## Explanation and example:

If you look at laws of [Finland](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/privacy-law-by-country/#Finland) or [Iceland](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/privacy-law-by-country/#Iceland) as stated here all require probably consent for collection.

In accordance with tg the given links there is no legitimate interest and Iceland also offers imprisonment. Are these binding or will legitimate interest and liability up to euro 20 million final.

Comment: Your question seems too broad. Can you provide a specific example of local law barring *legitimate interest* and what article(s) of the GDPR it contradicts?

Comment: Edited is it clearer?

Comment: The linked article is quite outdated and outright misinformed. The GDPR is closely based on the EU Data Protection Directive from '95 which all EU member states had implemented through national laws. All of these laws allowed for legitimate interest as well. It was *never* the case that consent was the sole legal basis, this is just what some less-informed bloggers claim. But to your specific question: yes, EU regulations such as the GDPR have precedence over national law, depending on the context. But there are many derogation clauses that allow member states to override certain aspects.

Comment: "All European countries" includes Iceland, but Iceland (and a good dozen or so other European countries) are not EU members. The GDPR obviously only has official status in the EU and EEA. Your question would probably benefit from a brief overview of whether you try to talk about the EU, the EEA, Europe as a whole (still problematic for several reasons of scope and well-definedness) or something else.

Comment: GDPR applies to whole EEA.

Comment: *"Do we have to follow all of the laws"* is also unclear. Who is "we" and under what circumstances do you mean? If you are operating in Iceland then obviously you have to follow Icelandic law. If you are operating in many countries and are violating the laws in some of them, but don't have a legal presence specifically in those countries, jurisdiction and enforcement questions are probably more relevant than the mere statutes themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have to follow all of the laws as many do not seem to allow "legitimate interest"

That is an inaccurate premise. *Legitimate interest* is cognizable under section 43(1) of Finland's [Personal Data Act](https://finlex.fi/en/laki/kaannokset/1999/en19990523_20000986.pdf) and articles 4 & 8.7 of Iceland's [Data Protection Act](https://www.personuvernd.is/information-in-english/greinar/nr/438). These I found by glancing at the Acts, but there might be additional sections/statutes in that direction.

> is following GDPR enough for europe?

Yes, but there is a caveat because on various matters the GDPR refers or delegates to national laws as well as members' *competent authority*.

Comment: One more thing will iceland's jail provision be there ?

Comment: Article 42 mentions imprisonment of up to three years (I'm assuming that the link points to the current version of the law). It is unclear how often, if ever, violations *actually* lead to imprisonment.

Comment: Yeah it will be surprising to see the CEO of a tech company being dragged to jail.

Comment: The imprisonment is in the law for cases where one can find *extreme* and *flagrant* violations that *also* might breach other laws or *contribute* to others breaching the law, especially when one can't get the person via the laws broken by the 3rd party. For example... ripping a person's personal surfing profile, then selling the profile without consent or knowledge to... an extortion ring and a hacker that uses the information to better hack the user's accounts to get to their credit card information.